# Why doesn't 'return' stop the function completely inside an 'if' statement?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently doing [this small tutorial](https://dom-tutorials.appspot.com/static/1.html) on accessing the DOM. Right at the bottom of the page, there's a small excersise on creating a function to go through all the nodes in the DOM and get the next node. I've got the code working, but I'm not sure exactly HOW it's working. This is less to do with the DOM and more to do with if/while loops.

This is the code:

```
nextNode = function(node) {
    if (node.firstChild) {
        return node.firstChild;
    }

    while (node) {
        if (node.nextSibling) {
            return node.nextSibling;
        }
        node=node.parentNode;
    };
    return node;
};
```

My questions are:

1. What is the first step that this function will take? For instance, it first checks if there's a child node for the selected node. If there is, it'll 'return' it. Shouldn't this end the function? I thought returning was a way to break out of a function? Why does it continue?
2. When it continues on to the while loop, it checks if there's a next sibling. It 'returns' this too. What is it returning it to? It then jumps to the parent node, and then checks again.

I hope my question makes sense. I'm just trying to understand the steps that are being taken during the execution of this function.

Comment: Are you sure it is not ending the function? Have you tried stepping through it to see what path it takes through the function and what the if statements evaluate to? You can add a `debugger;` line as the first line of the function if you want to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` works as you suppose it does - it terminates the function call completely. What your function does is basically a single step in deep DOM tree walkthrough:

1. checks whether the node has a child and returns it if it does. If it doesn't,
2. checks whether the node has a following sibling and returns it if it does. If it doesn't,
3. checks whether the node's parent has a following sibling and returns it if it does (loops recursively). If there is really no following node,
4. returns `null`, (because it exits the `while` loop only when `node` isn't defined).

Comment: Thanks, I'll update that. It seemed inconsequential to me, so I didn't go looking for the default value of `parentNode` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This code is defining the function to be called at a later point. That function returns a value.

These if and while conditions determine what is returned.

The first `if` checks if the node has a child. If so, it returns it, *ending the function execution* right there.

*If it doesn't*, the script continues to the `while` loop.

Again, if the node has a sibling, it returns it, *ending the function*. Only if there is no sibling does it continue to the parent.

When it's done traversing, it returns whatever is in the final value of `node`.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you need to realize that this function is designed to be *called multiple times in a loop*. Each time the function is called it will return exactly once, with one node value. On each call it can follow a different path through the function.

> For instance, it first checks if there's a child node for the selected node. If there is, it'll 'return' it. Shouldn't this end the function?

It *does* end the function, *if* there's a child node, because the `return` statement is inside the `if`. Otherwise it will continue with the rest of the function. Either way, it will get to the next nodes on subsequent calls of the function.

> When it continues on to the while loop, it checks if there's a next sibling. It 'returns' this too. What is it returning it to?

The calling function, as usual, assuming it didn't already end the call by returning a value from the `if` at the top of the function or from a previous iteration of that `while` loop.

> It then jumps to the parent node, and then checks again.

Only if it didn't yet return.